# How can I adjust my code to identify if all values of an array are distinct given the test inputs?

Tags: java, arrays, distinct-values

I am unsure as to why my code does not give the correct outputs for the test data which has been provided to me.

> Write a procedure 'allDistinct' that takes an array of objects and returns true iff they are all distinct (no two identical).

> Your procedure must work for all classes, You may type it using a variable type T

```java
<T> boolean allDistinct(T[] a)
{
    boolean r = true;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++)
        {
            if (a[i] == a[j])
            {
                r = false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return r;
}
```

[image: test results]

I have tried using `.equals()` instead of `==` but this resulted in no change and I am not sure why it is still incorrect.

Comment: What do you think happens if `j` equals `i`?

Comment: You should use `==` to compare object in your example!

Answer (score 1):

This is very simple task.

First of all, you should compare two objects with type `T` using `equals()`.

Your task is to put all data into a `HashSet` collection. And if the final size of the collection is less thant the length of the array, it means, that the array contains not distinct values.

```java
public static <T> boolean isAllDistinct(T[] arr) {
    Set<T> unique = new HashSet<>();

    for (T item : arr)
        if (!unique.add(item))
            return false;

    return true;
}
```

or using `Stream`

```java
public static <T> boolean isAllDistinct(T[] arr) {
    return Arrays.stream(arr).collect(Collectors.toSet()).size() == arr.length;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you were right, you absolutely need to use `equals` and not `==` (see, e.g., [What is the difference between == and equals() in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7520432/2422776)).

Second, as [Umeshwaran's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75282892/2422776)'s states, by "naively" looping over `i` and `j`, you have multiple cases where `i` and `j` are the same, and thus you'd be comparing an object to itself and wrongly returning `false`.

Third, while this has no effect on the *correctness* of the solution, from a performance perspective you should use the early return idom. Once you found a duplicate value there's no chance of it getting "unduplicated", so it's pointless to continue iterating over the rest of the array:

```java
<T> boolean allDistinct(T[] a) {
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)  {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < a.length; j++) {    // changed j=0 to j=i+1
            if (a[i] == a[j]) {
                return false; // Early return
            }
        }
    }
    
    return true;
}
```

Having said all of that, it may be easier to let Java's `Set`s do the heavy lifting for you, although this is tradeoff between runtime complexity and memory complexity:

```java
<T> boolean allDistinct(T[] a) {
    Set<T> tempSet = new HashSet<>(Arrays.asList(a));
    return tempSet.size() == a.length;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct , but you have made a minor mistake which is making it false .

```
<T> boolean allDistinct(T[] a)
{
    boolean r = true;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i+1; j < a.length; j++)     // changed j=0 to j=i+1
        {
            if (a[i] == a[j])
            {
                r = false;
            }
        }
    }
    
    return r;
}
```

I have changed `j=0` to `j=i+1` , because  when looping again , you are checking if both first elements are equal and it is failing

Comment: I think you meant `j = i + 1`.

Comment: @Mureinik thanks for correcting me . Forgot that